# Concatenate multiple UIImage into a single MLMultiArray

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, coreml

Edit: One way to solve it is to make the model takes in 25 RGB images, instead of a single 75 channels image.

I have a CoreML model which take [1, 75, 360, 600] MLMultiArray as input.
75 is the number of channels. And this array is a concatenation of 25 RGB images.
My RGB images are stored as UIImage.
For now, I'm using a for loop to assign the value for the MLMultiArray, and it is super slow.
I'm wondering is there any thing I can do to accelerate the copying?
Demo code is here:

```
var dummyInput = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [1, 75, 360, 600], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
for i in 0..<75 {
    for x in 0..<Int(img.size.width) {
        for y in 0..<Int(img.size.height) {
            dummyInput![[0, NSNumber(value: i), NSNumber(value: y), NSNumber(value: x)]] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make Set collection and run for, O-notation of Set is O(1)

Comment: How can I use set in this scenario? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: Does it have to be (1, 75, 360, 600) or can it be (25, 3, 360, 600) or even (25, 1, 3, 300, 600)? In other words, maybe you can run this as a batch or as a sequence.

Comment: Yes, it has to be a 75 channels input, because the conv kernel has 75 channels. One way to solve this is to make the model takes in 25 images, then concat them inside the model.